# Pointers and segmentation faults in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to read some `float`s from a file into an array I've created defined as such:

```
float *taps[3];
```

and I'm reading the floats in from the file  as such:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
fscanf(tapsInput, "%f", taps[i]);
}
```

I know that segmentation faults occur when a pointer is pointing so something wrong, but I'm not sure what is wrong with my code in this set up.

Comment: `float taps[3];` `fscanf(tapsInput, "%f", &taps[i]);`

Comment: @AlexD then you'd need to take the address to pass to scanf.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sure, I just added it.

Comment: @AlexD I've tried that but when I try and compile the program it gives me an warning. Specifically: "warning: %f expects argument of type 'float *' but argument 3 has type 'float **' I assumed that would not make it work

Comment: @Nick Did you remove `*` from the declaration?

Comment: @AlexD No because I have to pass it in to another function that takes a pointer to an array of floats. If I remove the * from the declaration my code won't compile.

Comment: Did you think it might have been useful to give that information in advance? And `float *taps[3];` is not an array of floats anyway.

Comment: @interjay I modeled my code off of code my professor gave me. If its not an array declaration what is it? I thought *taps[3] was the same as
    *(taps+3)

Comment: It's an array of pointers to float. Without knowing why you think you need this type, the best advice you can be given is to switch to using an array of floats `float taps[3];`. But it seems like there is some information you aren't telling us.

Comment: @Interjay the only other information is what I mentioned earlier. One of the inputs to another function in my code has an argument of float * and is supposed to take an array of floats. Thats why I initialized my taps array as I did. I think what I forgot to do was malloc it. So for example if I did ' taps = malloc(3*sizeof(float))' would that work?

Comment: Then you should use an array of floats `float taps[3]` and pass it to the function with simply `func(taps)`. Arrays automatically turn into pointers when used in an expression such as passing to a function, so you'll get the `float *` you need.

Answer (score 4):

> *I know that segmentation faults occur when a pointer is pointing so something wrong*

So does in your code. In your case, `taps[i]` is unitialized and points to *invalid* memory. so, before you can store anything in `taps[i]`, you need to allocate memory to it.

On an other approach, I don't see the reason for `taps` to be an array of pointer-to-`float`. You can simply do

```
float taps[3];
```

and then, pass the address of the individual elemnts to `fscanf()`, like

```
fscanf(tapsInput, "%f", &taps[i]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I actually have to pass a pointer to the beginning of a float array to another function in my code. I thought *taps[3] was the same as *(taps+3). Would it be more accurate to declare the pointer to the beginning of the array and then mallow 4 array elements?

Answer (score 1):

AlexD has it: `float *taps[3];` is an array of pointers to `float` but you don't have anywhere for the data to actually *go*.

Here's working code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

float taps[3];
int
main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      fscanf(stdin, "%f", &taps[i]);
  }
  printf("Values: %f %f %f", taps[0], taps[1], taps[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
$ gcc taps.c
$ ./a.out
42
33.5
0.01
Values: 42.000000 33.500000 0.010000
$
```

And here's why your code didn't work. When you write `float taps[3];`, you're declaring space for 3 **pointers** to `float`, that is, 3 addresses. You don't, however, initialize them, so the data in them is going to be whatever random bits happened to be at those locations the last time they were set.  When you attempt to set them with your `fprintf`, the system looks at the contents, finds whatever address happens to be there, say `0xBEEF`, and tries to send the data there.  Luckily, that's not a place where you can put data, so it throws a segmentation fault. If you weren't lucky, it would happen to be someplace you *could* write your data, which means that sometime in the future you might have something *really* weird happen because you muddled with the memory.

Now, when you use `float taps[3];`, you are now defining a location in memory which starts where `tabs[0]` is placed and has room for three floats.  Then your statement

```
fscanf(stdin, "%f", &taps[i]);
```

takes that array, finds the *address of the element* -- that's what the `&` operator does, and puts your value there.

In other words, `float *taps[3];` in an array of *addresses* of floats; `float taps[3];` is actually allocating space for 3 `floats`.

**Update**

It's easier to write code in an answer than a comment.

Alex, you need to think out what your code is saying.  `float *taps[3];` is, as we said, an array of pointers to `float`, so each `float*` element is an address. The `float taps[3];` is an actual array of `float`s, so each element is a `float`. So, say, `taps[2]` is itself a `float`.

(Notice, by the way, that you could *write* `taps[3]` and the compiler wouldn't care, because C doesn't check bounds. That would *mean* that the computer is going to look at whatever is at the address next to `taps[2]` and treat it as a `float` no matter what's actually there.)

The `&` operator takes the address of its right-hand side, so then when we give `fscanf` an argument of `&taps[i]` we're taking the *address* of that float, and passing it to `fscanf`.  An address of a float is a pointer to `float`, or a `float*`.

Now, here's where some weirdness comes in.  In C, the name of an *array* basically represents an address.  So, if I have a function with the prototype `foo(float[])` it says the function expects an array of `float`.  The name of an array is essentially a reference to the address of the first value, so this code would work:

```
void foo(float[] bar){
  // print three floats in an array, and God;s help you if there 
  // aren't three there.
  for(int ix=0; ix<4; ix++){
    printf("%f\n",bar[ix]);
  }
}
float taps[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
foo(taps);
```

... but if I tried `foo(*taps)` it wouldn't compile. Why?

Imagine this analogy. The address of my house is 1662. So, when I want to give people a reference to my house, I tell them it's number 1662. But '1662' is just the number on my house: the thing at the address 1662 is my house.

What would it mean to get the address of "1662"? Nothing -- that's just a number -- the *address* doesn't take any space. Similarly, in C, the name `taps` represents the address of a place in memory -- but that is just a number, it doesn't take any space. So when you say `*taps` you're taking the address of a number; that's meaningless and so it doesn't compile.

Now, *since the name of an array is just an address*, we could have declared our function `foo` like this:

```
void foo(float*) {
```

*which would be equally valid.*

In fact, in C, for any array `T` and integer `i`,  this is an identity:

```
*(T+i) == T[i]
```

and specifically `T` represents the same address as `&T[0]`.

So, now, think it out.  You have an array in some function `quux` that calls `foo(float*)`:

```
void quux() {
  float taps[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
  foo(taps);  // This compiles: you're giving the function 
              // an array name, and that represents the address
              // of an array
  // but foo(*taps) WON'T compile: that's the address of the address
  // of an array.
  return ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Martin. This is a really detailed answer and solves some of my questions. I need to pass a pointer to the beginning of a float array to one of my later functions which is why I declared my array as such. I've tried using your declaration and passing the array to my function as 
    *taps
but it returns an error. What is the proper way to do this?